# obfuscating nineoldandroids and android-switch-backport with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, nineoldandroids, android-switch

I 'am using proguard with eclipse to obfuscate a android proyect which has nineoldandroid library and switch backport, I get the following warnings:

```
Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/BuildConfig.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.BuildConfig]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$attr.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$attr]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$color.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$color]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$dimen.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$dimen]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$drawable.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$drawable]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$id.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$id]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$layout.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$layout]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$string.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$string]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$style.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$style]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R$styleable.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R$styleable]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/R.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.R]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/Switch.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/SwitchPreference$Listener.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.SwitchPreference$Listener]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/SwitchPreference.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.SwitchPreference]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/TwoStatePreference$SavedState$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.TwoStatePreference$SavedState$1]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/TwoStatePreference$SavedState.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.TwoStatePreference$SavedState]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [android-switch-backport/bin/classes/org/jraf/android/backport/switchwidget/TwoStatePreference.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.TwoStatePreference]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/BuildConfig.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.BuildConfig]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorInflater.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorInflater]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorSet$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorSet$1]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorSet$AnimatorSetListener.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorSet$AnimatorSetListener]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorSet$Builder.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorSet$Builder]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorSet$Dependency.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorSet$Dependency]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorSet$DependencyListener.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorSet$DependencyListener]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorSet$Node.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorSet$Node]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/AnimatorSet.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorSet]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ArgbEvaluator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ArgbEvaluator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/FloatEvaluator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.FloatEvaluator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/FloatKeyframeSet.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.FloatKeyframeSet]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/IntEvaluator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.IntEvaluator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/IntKeyframeSet.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.IntKeyframeSet]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/Keyframe$FloatKeyframe.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.Keyframe$FloatKeyframe]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/Keyframe$IntKeyframe.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.Keyframe$IntKeyframe]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/Keyframe$ObjectKeyframe.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.Keyframe$ObjectKeyframe]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/Keyframe.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.Keyframe]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/KeyframeSet.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.KeyframeSet]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ObjectAnimator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$1]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$10.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$10]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$11.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$11]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$12.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$12]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$13.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$13]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$14.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$14]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$2.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$2]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$3.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$3]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$4.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$4]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$5.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$5]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$6.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$6]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$7.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$7]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$8.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$8]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat$9.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat$9]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PreHoneycombCompat.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PreHoneycombCompat]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PropertyValuesHolder$IntPropertyValuesHolder.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$IntPropertyValuesHolder]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/PropertyValuesHolder.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.PropertyValuesHolder]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/TimeAnimator$TimeListener.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.TimeAnimator$TimeListener]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/TimeAnimator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.TimeAnimator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/TypeEvaluator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.TypeEvaluator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ValueAnimator$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator$1]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ValueAnimator$2.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator$2]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ValueAnimator$3.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator$3]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ValueAnimator$4.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator$4]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ValueAnimator$5.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator$5]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ValueAnimator$AnimatorUpdateListener.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimatorUpdateListener]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ValueAnimator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/util/FloatProperty.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.util.FloatProperty]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/util/IntProperty.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.util.IntProperty]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/util/NoSuchPropertyException.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.util.NoSuchPropertyException]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/util/Property.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.util.Property]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/util/ReflectiveProperty.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.util.ReflectiveProperty]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewHelper$Honeycomb.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper$Honeycomb]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewHelper.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorHC$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorHC$1]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorHC$AnimatorEventListener.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorHC$AnimatorEventListener]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorHC$NameValuesHolder.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorHC$NameValuesHolder]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorHC$PropertyBundle.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorHC$PropertyBundle]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorHC.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorHC]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorICS$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorICS$1]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorICS.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorICS]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC$1]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC$AnimatorEventListener.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC$AnimatorEventListener]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC$NameValuesHolder.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC$NameValuesHolder]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC$PropertyBundle.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC$PropertyBundle]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorPreHC]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: class [nineoldandroids/bin/classes/com/nineoldandroids/view/animation/AnimatorProxy.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.nineoldandroids.view.animation.AnimatorProxy]
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Note: there were 4469 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] Warning: there were 90 classes in incorrectly named files.
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero]          You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero]          The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero]          If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero]          you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero]     at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:133)
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero]     at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:196)
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78)
[2014-06-04 11:07:36 - Tappsi_pasajero]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

How could I fix this issue? How does the configuration file should be set?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because Proguard is detecting a conflict between your project directory structure and the fully qualified class names of those classes that are part of android-switch-backport and nineoldandroids. [Proguard documentation](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html) explains this error.

The easiest way to get rid of this is to add a line a line with `-ignorewarnings` in the proguard configuration file. By adding that line to the proguard config file proguard, will not obfuscate those class files, but I don't think you are concerned about that since they are third-party libraries. Adding that line will get rid of the warning messages, but Proguard should work on your own class files even if you don't add that line.